# Could't connect to node? ethereum wallet installing error

Tags: wallets

Im getting an error message when trying to install a new ethereum wallet
any ideas on how to solve it

[image: error message]

Comment: What's your network like? Are you behind a firewall which is blocking outgoing connections?

Comment: my network is fine, my internet is fine, I run as administer, I've deactivated my trusted application mode in Kaspersky